# jquery ajax post with xml returning bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request

I’m currently having an issue on my following code, POST request is returning “Bad Request” error.

```
function UpdateOrderStatus(){

var domainName = "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx/1_1/MainService.svc/webapi/UpdateOrderStatus";
var orderData = {
    "wsCodeCrypt" : "xxxxxx",
    "caUid" : "xxxxxx",
    "caPwd" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "slsDoc" : "SO",
    "slsRef" : "00001",
    "status" : "pending"
};

$.ajax({
    url: domainName, 
    method: "POST",
    data: orderData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml);
    },
    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
    }
});
```

}

The code works if I use the full URL and ditch the entire “data: orderData” option. Anyone knows what the issue is?

Comment: Do you mean that using the full URL in the `url` option of `$.ajax` works, without changing the `method`?

Comment: your datatype is xml but you are sending a json

Comment: @masadwin OP is not sending the data in JSON. Please read the code again.

Comment: read it again, look like JSON to me. what does `var orderData = {...}` look like to you? that same variable is being used in ajax block

Comment: @31piy yes the code works if i use the full url in url option

Comment: you also said you ditch the entire `data: orderData` right? which indicates that when you say you will send 'xml' in your dataType but send json instead, the server can't parse it. Hence a bad request. When you ditch the data entirely, the server does not encounter any issue while parsing because there is nothing to parse?

Comment: I have made multiple GET requests with similar syntax and there were no issues. So far what I've discovered is that the server isn't accepting caUid data hence causing the request to fail. With full URL minus caUid and I get the exact same error. Any ideas what caused this? It worked in my other GET requests.

Comment: @masadwin - Again, its not JSON for the AJAX request. It is a plain JS object, which is used by jQuery to automatically prepare request params. [Read it here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).